# SQL Server (2012) hangs when referencing Access database (2010) via ACE provider

Tags: sql-server-2012, ms-access-2010, linked-server

My SQL Server 2012 server with several linked servers hangs when i try to add a linked server to an Access database using the ACE 12 provider.  Once it hangs, SQL management studio stops displaying linked server catalog objects.  I have enabled InProcess on the ACE provider.

How do I fix this/add the Access DB as a linked server without this problem?

For context, I have a MS Access database (about 1GB in size) with about a dozen tables that I want to load into corresponding tables in a SQL server 2012 database.  The data is loaded on demand when a user process a button in an Excel worksheet.  (worksheet calls stored procedure, stored procedure calls DTS package)

I want to change this process to remove the DTS package because users will no longer have permission to run DTS packages or xp_cmdshell.

I think the DTS package could easily be replaced using a linked server or even OPENDATASOURCE query, but I'm having trouble using the linked server (constantly hangs when i try to add it)

Comment: Is there some reason you don't just migrate the Access tables/data to SQL Server 2012? Or is that what you're trying to do here with your "linked server"?

Comment: @HK1 this is a legacy process that we are trying to work around.  the access database is used for some other stuff beyond just storing data, but the data is used by other processes.  Queries as they are in the access DB won't work with linked tables.